# Need simple graphical interface for Oracle IMP utility

Tags: oracle, import

the company receives several Oracle database dumps from clients for analysis. My programmers are not Oracle literate and find it difficult to restore the dumps using the IMP utility.

They need a graphical interface over IMP to make restoring the dumps easier.

It should make it easy to restore the dump to a different database user AND to a different table space without the need to use arcane command line options.

suggestions anyone ?

Thank you,

Fábio

Answer (score 1):

```
Here are the commands that I run in sqlplus to create the directory and sample shell scripts that do the imports and exports:
```

Commands to run in sqlplus prior to running inport:

```
grant create any directory to EPADMRT;
create or replace directory MY_DIR as '/content_services/alan';
```

Sample import shell script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/ksh  
export ORACLE_SID=PADMRT
impdp EPADMRT/ART schemas=CHECK_DB directory=my_dir dumpfile=CHECK_DB.dmp logfile=impdp_CHECK_DB.log
```

For an export, here is what I run in sqlplus:

```
grant create any directory to EPADMRT;
create or replace directory MY_DIR as '/u01/home/oracle/alan';
```

And here is a sample shell script that I run to do the export:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
export ORACLE_SID=PADMRT
expdp  EPADMRT/ART schemas=CHECK_DB directory=MY_DIR dumpfile=CHECK_DB.dmp logfile=expdpCHECK_DB.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_oracle/oracle_detail_win.html) but found it on a quick search of the web. It might do what you want.

Comment: Checked it. Its a lot more complicated than what I need. Seens to have the features I need. I´ll get approval for the purchase and see if it does the job. Thanks.